# Setup a development server on linode

Tags: linux, node.js, linode

I have an Ubuntu server on linode running a node.js/mongo app. I realize I should have set up a development server first but what is the best way to do it now? I was planning on cloning the current image and installing it on a new linode. Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clone from right in the Linode.com interface:

http://blog.linode.com/2007/11/16/clone-a-linode-to-another-linode/

When you log in, under 'Linodes' there should be a 'Clone' tab - this is where you specify the configuration and/or images you want to clone. You can then select the destination linode on the following screen.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was planning on doing. I wasn't sure if it was necessary to get a complete duplicate of the system or install a new image, but I think it would help eliminate bugs from a different setup rather than the code itself. And for those that closed it as off topic, try reading the FAQ next time: - software tools commonly used by programmers
 -practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession